# Get Object Property names Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to c# and this is my question.
I have given  users to select their Search by option from a drop down list & I'm passing both **Searchterm** & **SearchBy**  as String parameters in my **search** method.

(Get() methods return `DbSet` of Items)

```
public virtual IQueryable<Item> Search(string searchTerm, string searchBy)
{
    if (searchBy == "Name")
    {
        var item = Get().Where(i => i.Name.Contains(searchTerm));

        return item;
    }

     if (searchBy == "Category")
    {
        var item = Get().Where(i => i.Category.Contains(searchTerm));
        return item;
    }
}
```

Name, Category are propertied of Item Model.
What I want is to use searchBy parameter directly instead of checking 
**if (searchBy=="Name")**.
It should be similar to this.

```
var item = Get().Where(i => i.searchBy.Contains(searchTerm));
```

Is it possible ? pls advice!

Comment: Why if else needed here, in block code is same, huh?

Comment: Seems that bad logic here is the problem.

Comment: are you sure in your second if statement the `where` clause is `i=>i.Name.Contains(searchTerm)` and not `i=>i.Category.Contains(searchTerm)` ?

Comment: It's possible, but not very straightforward due to the way the language works. You'd have to delve into using reflection and/or Expression trees, which is pretty tricky stuff for a beginner.

Comment: second "if" contains typo, should be:  var item = Get().Where(i => i.Category.Contains(searchTerm));

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq dynamic queries for user search screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539270/linq-dynamic-queries-for-user-search-screens)

Comment: @Praveen Prasannan
tx.. got ur point!

Comment: @Tolga Evcimen 
 it should be "i.Category.Name" since Category is a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the linq dynamic query library, as described in Scott Guthrie's [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx):

```
var item = Get().Where("@0.Contains(@1)", searchBy, searchTerm);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will allow you to search dynamically in your object :

```
   private static List<T> Search<T>(string searchFor, string searchBy, List<T> searchIn)
    {
         return searchIn.Where(i => i.GetType().GetProperty(searchBy).GetValue(i).ToString().Contains(searchFor)).ToList();    
    }
```

here's how to use it :

```
Console.WriteLine(Search<Users>("1", "ID", user).FirstOrDefault().Name);                 Console.ReadLine();
```

note now you don't care what is the object ...

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s93GE.png)

Comment: No, reflection does not work like this with Entity Framework. It cannot compile such an expression into an SQL query. [Read the linked duplicate suggestion for the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539270/linq-dynamic-queries-for-user-search-screens).